# Find elements of regex-array in data array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

**Issue**

I need to compare two arrays to get all missing elements. The difficulty is, that some values are case insensitive.

**Data**

First of all I have these two arrays:

```
const data  = [ 'There', 'is', 'a', 'Word', 'there' ]           // pure data
const query = [ /^There$/i, /^is$/, /^a$/, /^Word$/, /^there$/ ]    // RegEx for case sensitivity
```

The second one is used to get some data from the DB, which gives me the result shown below.

*DB query result data*

```
let dbResult = [ 'word', 'there', 'is' ]
```

Now I want to know which elements of the original data are missing in the result.

As you can see the first element should be case insensitive, that means it is existing in the dbResult-array.

**Expected Result**

```
[ 'a', 'Word' ]
```

1. `Word` is case sensitive -> Not found in result
2. `There` is case insensitive -> Found in result

**My failing attempt**

I already tried to use `_.difference(data, dbResult)` but with that `There` will be also in the result array, which should not be, as it should be handled as case insensitive and there is an existing `there` in the dbResult-array

Comment: why is the result out of order 'word-there-is'??

Comment: I did not think about that. This is like I get the data in my application. But does it matter for this question here?

Comment: depends on the solution i guess. you could try `_.differenceWith(array, [values], [comparator])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
const missing = data.filter((word, i) => {
  return !dbResult.some(res => res.match(query[i]))
})

// > ["a", "Word"]
```